# SafeCracker Not Working?

Tags: templates, channel-entries, safecracker

I'm trying out SafeCracker for the first time. What I've done:

- SafeCracker module is installed
- Channel {test_profiles} is created with 1 field: {full_name}

The following code outputs nothing between the tag pair:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<form>
    {exp:safecracker channel="test_profiles" datepicker="no" include_jquery="no" return="registration/form" safecracker_head="no"}
        <input name="title" type="text">
        <input name="full_name" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    {/exp:safecracker}
</form>
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**EDIT 1:**
I went to Addons -> Modules -> SafeCracker. I saw a list of my Channels there, including `test_profiles`. I checked the "Allow guests to post entries?" checkbox and selected one of the members from the "Set the member_id to use for guests." drop down menu. Afterwards, I viewed the template output again. Now I see a <script> and <style> inside the <form> tags. I still don't see my text field, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the member group have permission to post to the channel?

CP Home > Members > Member Groups > Edit Member Group > Channel Assignment

---

This **[part of the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#allowing-guests-to-post-entries)** should help you allowing guests to post:

It certainly helps me to create a "Logged Out Members" member_group and a single user in that group to take ownership of those entries. (In my case their member_id is '2' as shown in tag example)

My tag looks a little like this:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="registrations"
                 return="foo/bar/ENTRY_ID"
                 logged_out_member_id="2"
                 ...
                 ...
```

My CP Home > Extensions > SafeCracker entry looks like this

[image: CP Home > Extensions > SafeCracker]

Comment: No, I have not done this! I have several member groups. How do I know which one to set?

Comment: It seems like I can enable all the member groups to have permission to post to the Channel. So, when the form is rendered and no one is logged in, who's posting?

Comment: I've just added to my main post to cover the "Who's posting comment"